# Object Detection live video desktop

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am looking to create a script that can process images from a selected window on the desktop and successfully identify when a specific object appears on the screen. It needs to be able to process video live and draw bounding boxes around the identified object on the screen in real time.

I'm no stranger to reading documentation so if anyone can just point me in the right direction I can learn how to set everything up on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Zero Shot https://blog.roboflow.com/zero-shot-object-tracking/ or YOLO https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-you-only-look-once-17f9280a47b0